# Can I change what appears (`?`) when `\ref` or a `\cite` fails?

Tags: bibtex, errors, cross-referencing

I find it very easy to screw up references.

Maybe I spelt a bibtex key wrong, or I updated the key for some reason (not knowing it was in use), or I put a space in the citation (`\cite(a,b)` vs `\cite{a,b}`).
Or I decide to remove the entire section that I cross reffed elsewhere with `\ref`, but forgot to delete the reference to it.
Or i forgot to compile the bibliography.

In these cases the output will normally contain a **?** in the place of the reference.

Because I have become too close to being burnt by this before (After submitting an article, only realizing on "one final last minute check" that in my last revision I had broken something,.) I now make a habit of doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `?` to make sure there are none where they are not expected.

But `?` is not a rare character in my documents, it likely occurs 2-5 times intentionally. It is quiet common in paper titles; and some times verious math symbols `\star` will be considered to be `?` when I do a search.

I would much rather the output for a broken reference be something else.
For example, `!!BORKED!!` that I could more easily search for and spot.

NB: a solution involving Biblatex rather than Bibtex would not be suitable.
One of the main things that causes this for me is switching from BibLaTeX, to BibTex. BibLaTeX is always happy with spaces in `\cite{a, b}`; bibtex, not so much.

Comment: Why don't you examine the console output or log file instead? Lots of editors even do this for you. Or you can parse the log with additional tools or just use `grep`.

Comment: I think this is unwise -- not that `!!BORKED!!` is itself unwise, but it may lead to not catching other problems before submission/finalization. Are you really not looking at the `.log` for warnings before you submit the document? There may, after all, be other potential problems (i.e., warnings) besides a missing reference or unknown bibkey.

Comment: @jon Honestly, no. My first and primary point of reference for if the document is correct is to look at the document. if it looks right, then it looks right. The log is often overflowing with `bad hbox` etc.
I mean I probably should check it more. But having both would be better.

Comment: Right, well that's what I mean: check the `.log` and you'll quickly learn about undefined labels and so on. A judicious use of `grep` will help you pinpoint the problems. (And, depending on the type of document, one that is 'overflowing' with bad boxes might not be something you want to rest satisfied with.)

Comment: Biblatex shows the cite key of the unresolved references